# micrologin phptoys $username in other pages

Tags: php

i use phpoys micro login system to login and register users to my website
but i cant figure out how i can display the $username in pages....

[micro login script](http://www.phptoys.com/download/micro-login-system-script.html)

I integrated this scrip in my website and it works great, but when i want to call `$username`, like in the login.php file for example in index.php the `$username` doesnt exist?

when i place `echo $_SESSION['userName'] ;` i get the username, bu if it was $username i could integrate his in other functions of my website. Is this solvable to read $username not only on he login.php script?

on he login page $username is called like this

```
if (isset($_POST['submitBtn'])){
    // Get user input
    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
}
```

Comment: Are You sure that You sending data via POST?

Comment: this is only in he login page, in other pages only $_SESSION['valdiuser'] gets checked by checkuser()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've logged in you'll be able to access the username from the $_SESSION variable.

To check whether the $_SESSION data has been set, use the function isset.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userName'])) {
   echo $_SESSION['userName'];
}
```

This will only display the username if you are logged in. To use the session data across onto other pages, be sure to place session_start(); up the top.

Comment: Thx lead me to the solution: if (isset($_SESSION['userName'])) {
 $username = isset( $_SESSION['userName'] ) ? $_SESSION['userName'] : '';  }
echo $username ;